# Nodejs local dependencies its not working when the build it's make

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules

I have an application developed in node and typescript, so to make this application more modular (something like libs in asp.net), I've been created two local packages to be more reusable and add them in my application as local package (npm i 'path-my-module').

But now I'd problems when I build my solution to make a deploy in test because this modules hasn't been included in the build.

I'm new in node and I didn't find much thing about how can I work in this case I would like to know how can I do in this case?

This approach it's right?

How can I use local dependencies and include them in my build to be deployed in test env?

More information:

My Package.json is more or less like this:

```
"dependencies": {
some imports ...
    "my-local-package-a": "file:../LocalPackageA",
    "my-local-package-b": "file:../LocalPackageB",
.... more imports,
  },
```

I'm using Gulp.js to automate the pipeline.
My gulp file:

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var ts = require("gulp-typescript");
var tsProject = ts.createProject("tsconfig.json");

var OUT_DIR = "dist";
var IN_DIR = "../MyAlexaApp";

// compile typescript
gulp.task("compile", function () {
    return tsProject.src()
        .pipe(tsProject())
        .js.pipe(gulp.dest(OUT_DIR));
});

// copy json files (e.g. localization json)
gulp.task("json", function () {
    return gulp.src(IN_DIR + "/**/*.json").pipe(gulp.dest(OUT_DIR));
});

gulp.task("default", gulp.parallel(["compile", "json"]));
```

My ts config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es6"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "../DealerSearchSkill",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    ".ask",
    "coverage",
    "skill-package",
    "infrasctructure",
    "/**/node_modules",
    "lambda/local/",
    "__tests__",
    "**/__mocks__"
  ]
}
```

Comment: In the code above, the only `require` statements I see are for Gulp.  When you create a module in Node, you have to require that module in order to use it within another module.  If you've already required your module, please show the contents of your module as well as the require statement so that the community can help troubleshoot.

Comment: Hi @tgmerritt the modules are used as a npm package, thank you for your answer. So I add using npm and after this I use "import declaration" to use them. I have doubts if I need add them in some configuration or just the declaration of them in the 'package.json' is enough to be imported during the build time... But I'll update the question.